# How to replace controls of edit an item of ASPxGridView with another grid with a different source table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

Instead of controls generated automatically when I press Edit I have to replace them with another grid that will have a different source table.
Is that possible?
The reason for this is that when I press Edit for an item, I need to have extra columns of other tables related to this which I want also to be updatable. Hope you got the idea. 
I am looking at this http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/EditFormTemplate.aspx 
Should this be the solution?
PS: I am new to devexpress :D

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress Support directly?

Comment: thanks for the question :) because I don't have bought a license yet, I am in trial. And they changed the status of my question there on private. So :D No help for those without buying the product :|

Comment: They offer a free 30 days trial http://www.devexpress.com/Home/Try.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understanding your question right this is the solution: http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/MasterDetail/MasterDetail.aspx

You need to implement child grids.